# Is visne > vin unique?

Tags: classical-latin, morphology, suffixes, enclitic, contraction

There is a contraction from the regular *visne* to *vin*.
Is the same contraction with *-ne* attested with other verbs in classical Latin?
I don't recall seeing questions like *loquerin Latine* or *haben equum* or *en Graecus*.
(Here **en < esne*; I'm not referring to *en ≈ ecce*.)
Is the phenomenon unique to *velle*?

Comment: I recall reading both sciesne and scin, but at least one of them in a modern translation (I think Harrius Potter et  philosophi lapis.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Weiss writes that

> "The interrogative enclitic particle -ne becomes -n in Plautus when apocope produces an acceptable coda" (p. 147, footnote 79), i.e. *-Vsn- > *-V ̅n- (I.B.8.b, p. 169).

He gives the following examples:

**scivin** (Pseud. 977), **vin** (Curc. 313).

He also says that "[v]erbal forms ending in -s often lose the s with compensatory lengthening" (p. 147, footnote 79), e.g. **nostin** (found in Terrence and Plautus).

More examples from "Syntax and Stilistik" (Szantyr et al. 1965/2016):

**ain** (from ais-ne), **audin**, **censen**, **pergin**, **scin**, **viden**, **vin** (p. 461).

Comment: The macron over the V doesn't seem to render well for me. Perhaps `V&#772;` or `V&#x304;` would be better? I don't know how others see all these characters. I just posted a solution to [the macron question](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/79) that works with any letter.

Answer (score 4):

I know of 2 others off the top of my head.

- *satin* from *satisne*

  Plautus, *Amphitruo* 604:

  > quas, malum, nugas? satin tu sanus es?

  Cicero, *De officiis* 3.73:

  > quid ergo? satin est hoc, ut non deliquisse videantur?
- *scin* from *scisne*, mentioned by Rafael in a comment

  Plautus, *Amphitruo* 671:

  > scin quam bono animo sim?

  Cicero, *Epistulae ad Atticum* 1.13.4:

  > tuus autem ille amicus (scin quem dicam? de quo tu ad me scripsisti, postea quam non auderet reprehendere laudare coepisse) nos, ut ostendit, admodum diligit, amplectitur, amat, aperte laudat, occulte, sed ita ut perspicuum sit, invidet.

Comment: I've seen "dan=dasne?"